# remove ripple effect on icon button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to have an icon who make the button's job ( loading )
But I would remove this round button effect of this icon

How can I do this ?
https://codepen.io/sebastiancz/pen/gOpjbar?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center">
      <div>
        <v-btn flat icon color="blue lighten-2">
          <v-icon>power</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

find it brother, use these both CSS and it will do the trick :

```
.v-btn:before {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.v-ripple__container {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

let me know if it works or not, will help you further if it won't

Comment: happy to help buddy @TheDevGuy and the fun part is this is the first time i came to know about `vuetify.js`

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
v-ripple="false"
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/ripple/#usage

Answer (score 1):

in vuetify 3 just use

```
<v-btn variant="plain">
```

documentation: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props-variant

Answer (score 0):

hi try this code hope it will help you:-

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center">
      <div>
        <v-btn color="blue lighten-2">
          <v-icon>power</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: No I just want the icon but not the circle effect

Answer (score 0):

i think this will will help you!!!

add this CSS

```
.v-btn:before {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

let me know if this works or not

Comment: and for remove the ripple during the click ?

Comment: i am checking that

Answer (score 0):

How to remove click/focus ripple animation on a Vuetify 3 v-btn button  component using css only ([playground demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlkd1OwzAMhV8lyhVIayIE3JQyjafgYpmmrjVaIH9K3KJp2ruTpN3oNiFN4i4+ts9nO8s9fXOO9R3QklYI2qkaYS4MIVVf1M7lZw4aa7CWBvwoZdHb71M4VqmJkKUNGtKoOoRXQT1o20PhpXMKBJ2/S9zaDskgVDxXTx2jcm75JyN73WyU4t/hh+x0v6QM61d8cpYqNJGAJAB2bl7xIcwJ3CkgobEO2uzAznYlZQvg7lik5ni9PvHuyX6YopUhcnYlMdbAS9IOCZ+doyWdUamd9Vjo2rHPYE38s9wqxkQQtDyaCRo/NcWCbhFdKDlvWhPbWlCy98wAcuM0X8Qy7juDUkPRWr14ZI/sicdZcCozCLrYxIsF8NFE0NkEg/JjdwNqrMyEh+cBMWqFqjchMa68eQT24AsPpgUP/taVLtqma12krlYbL3+IB1fSfIWLWzch33l5HPJ/O2e3ZLVKxMOM5kEjeuigqx9/1DDA)):

```js
<template>
  <v-btn class="remove-ripple">Without ripple</v-btn>
  <v-btn>With ripple</v-btn>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .remove-ripple :deep(.v-ripple__container) {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.v-btn:hover:before { background-color: transparent }
```

Comment: Curious why this was downvoted, as it works in the codepen and doesn't use `!important`, which is an antipattern usually.