# how to disable ripple in nuxt js with vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have created a NuxtJS project and selected Vuetify as the UI framework from default selections. I would like to disable the ripple effect on buttons and other possible vuetify components. Since there is no dedicated Vuetify.js file and all are configured in the nuxt.config.js file, I tried editing the same.

```
vuetify: {
button: {
  disableRipple: true,
},
}
```

but no use. So, any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, found out that, [remove ripple effect on icon button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60756963/remove-ripple-effect-on-icon-button?rq=1) accepted answer solved my case too. Answer maybe common but question is different

In case if anything changes/for future reference,

```
.v-btn:before {
   opacity: 0 !important;
}
.v-ripple__container {
   opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Thanks to [Anant Vikram Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11451001/anant-vikram-singh)